# Call a Function of keyboard on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, dom-events

I am new in HTML and want to convert a key press to a simple button. Means the event which is firing on Keyboard press want to call on button click. This is my function:

```
 var keyPressed = function(e) {

     if(!e) e = window.event;
     switch (e.keyCode)
     {
         case 37:   // left arrow
             human.moveCannon = (e.type == "keyup") ? "N" : "L";
             break;
         case 39:   // right arrow
             human.moveCannon = (e.type == "keyup") ? "N" : "R";
             break;
         case 32:   // spacebar
             human.cannonFire = (e.type == "keyup") ? false : true;
             break;
         case 67:   // 'c'
             if (e.type == "keydown")
                 insertCoin();
             break;
    }
};
```

I am calling this function with keyboard key presses and it is working fine.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPressed, true);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyPressed, true);
```

Now I'm calling this on button click but it is not been called. I just want to call thisnon button click

```
<input type="button" value="Left"  onclick="keyPressed(event)">
```

What are the errors I know I'm not passing the correct parameter in keypressed function. I needed it don't know much about html.

Comment: Just need to call this keypressed function I will handle other things after switch

Comment: Depending on what you want the button to do you could change the onclick to `onclick="keyPressed({keyCode: 32, type: 'keydown'})"` which would be the same as pressing space

Comment: @MartinPersson i tried this but still function is not invoking. i am checking by using alert but its not working

Comment: @ZaheerUdeen plz can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: @FastSnail fiddle? don't know

Comment: @ZaheerUdeen You would have to define keyPressed globally: https://jsfiddle.net/dL0nx95q/1/

Comment: @MartinPersson thanks! it working but i have one more issue. i cannot make this function globally because there are something like that   human.moveCannon = (e.type == "keyup") ? "N" : "L";  which wont be called if make this function right up with the start of script tag. Human.movecannon is behind my function

Comment: @MartinPersson Stiil not be able to call this function.. Place of defining function is reallly disturbing me. Cannot be called if declared right behind all the code and can be called if decalared globally but issues are same because there are a lot of code right behind this function. Any idea how can i deal with it??

Comment: Would need a more complete example to debug